# hash code judge system past edition

Tags: hashcode

There is a way to use the judge system of the past edition of the google hash code competition?
I'm doing practice with the problems statements of the past editions and I want to calculate the score of my submissions.

Answer (score 1):

The judges for previous years are not accessible to the public - you will have to write the judge yourself which, although frustrating, shouldn't be too hard to do.